# Unable to import package (pytables) in iPython/Spyder in Anaconda 2.4 (python 3.5) even though it is installed

Tags: python, package, ipython, anaconda, package-managers

Have jut installed Anaconda 2.4 (Python 3.5) on my 64-bit windows PC.
I have updated the packages with

```
conda update conda
conda update --all
```

I am trying to import Pytables but it is throwing follwoing error

```
import pytables
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-1-5f8d94f079d6>", line 1, in <module>
import pytables

ImportError: No module named 'pytables'
```

It is weird as Pytables package is very much there in the package list

```
# packages in environment at C:\Anaconda3:
#
alabaster                 0.7.6                    py35_0    <unknown>
anaconda                  2.4.0               np110py35_0    <unknown>
anaconda-client           1.1.2                    py35_0    defaults
argcomplete               1.0.0                    py35_1    <unknown>
astropy                   1.0.6               np110py35_0    defaults
babel                     2.1.1                    py35_0    <unknown>
beautifulsoup4            4.4.1                    py35_0    <unknown>
bitarray                  0.8.1                    py35_1    <unknown>
blaze                     0.8.3                     <pip>
blaze-core                0.8.3                    py35_0    <unknown>
bokeh                     0.10.0                   py35_0    <unknown>
boto                      2.38.0                   py35_0    <unknown>
bzip2                     1.0.6                    vc14_2  [vc14]  <unknown>
cffi                      1.2.1                    py35_0    <unknown>
clyent                    1.1.0                    py35_0    defaults
colorama                  0.3.3                    py35_0    <unknown>
comtypes                  1.1.2                    py35_0    <unknown>
conda                     3.18.6                   py35_0    defaults
conda-build               1.18.2                   py35_0    defaults
conda-env                 2.4.4                    py35_2    defaults
configobj                 5.0.6                    py35_0    <unknown>
console_shortcut          0.1.1                    py35_1    <unknown>
cryptography              1.0.2                    py35_0    <unknown>
curl                      7.45.0                   vc14_0  [vc14]  <unknown>
cycler                    0.9.0                    py35_0    defaults
cython                    0.23.4                   py35_0    <unknown>
cytoolz                   0.7.4                    py35_0    <unknown>
datashape                 0.4.7               np110py35_1    <unknown>
decorator                 4.0.4                    py35_0    <unknown>
docutils                  0.12                     py35_1    <unknown>
fastcache                 1.0.2                    py35_0    <unknown>
flask                     0.10.1                   py35_1    <unknown>
freetype                  2.5.5                    vc14_0  [vc14]  <unknown>
greenlet                  0.4.9                    py35_0    <unknown>
h5py                      2.5.0               np110py35_4    <unknown>
hdf5                      1.8.15.1                 vc14_3  [vc14]  <unknown>
idna                      2.0                      py35_0    <unknown>
ipykernel                 4.1.1                    py35_0    <unknown>
ipython                   4.0.0                    py35_1    <unknown>
ipython-genutils          0.1.0                     <pip>
ipython-notebook          4.0.4                    py35_3    <unknown>
ipython-qtconsole         4.0.1                    py35_4    <unknown>
ipython_genutils          0.1.0                    py35_0    <unknown>
ipywidgets                4.1.0                    py35_0    <unknown>
itsdangerous              0.24                     py35_0    <unknown>
jdcal                     1.0                      py35_0    <unknown>
jedi                      0.9.0                    py35_0    <unknown>
jinja2                    2.8                      py35_0    <unknown>
jpeg                      8d                       vc14_0  [vc14]  <unknown>
jsonschema                2.4.0                    py35_0    <unknown>
jupyter                   1.0.0                    py35_0    <unknown>
jupyter-client            4.1.1                     <pip>
jupyter-console           4.0.3                     <pip>
jupyter-core              4.0.6                     <pip>
jupyter_client            4.1.1                    py35_0    <unknown>
jupyter_console           4.0.3                    py35_0    <unknown>
jupyter_core              4.0.6                    py35_0    <unknown>
launcher                  1.0.0                         4    <unknown>
libpng                    1.6.17                   vc14_1  [vc14]  <unknown>
libsodium                 1.0.3                         0    <unknown>
libtiff                   4.0.6                    vc14_1  [vc14]  defaults
lxml                      3.4.4                    py35_0    <unknown>
markupsafe                0.23                     py35_0    <unknown>
matplotlib                1.5.0               np110py35_0    defaults
menuinst                  1.2.2                    py35_0    defaults
mistune                   0.7.1                    py35_0    <unknown>
msvc_runtime              1.0.1                    vc14_0  [vc14]  defaults
multipledispatch          0.4.8                    py35_0    <unknown>
nbconvert                 4.0.0                    py35_0    <unknown>
nbformat                  4.0.1                    py35_0    <unknown>
networkx                  1.10                     py35_0    <unknown>
nltk                      3.1                      py35_0    <unknown>
node-webkit               0.10.1                        0    <unknown>
nose                      1.3.7                    py35_0    <unknown>
notebook                  4.0.6                    py35_0    <unknown>
numexpr                   2.4.4               np110py35_0    <unknown>
numpy                     1.10.1                   py35_0    <unknown>
odo                       0.3.4                    py35_0    <unknown>
openpyxl                  2.2.6                    py35_0    <unknown>
openssl                   1.0.2d                   vc14_0  [vc14]  <unknown>
pandas                    0.17.1              np110py35_0    defaults
patch                     2.5.9                         1    defaults
path.py                   8.1.2                    py35_1    defaults
patsy                     0.4.0               np110py35_0    <unknown>
pep8                      1.6.2                    py35_0    <unknown>
pickleshare               0.5                      py35_0    <unknown>
pillow                    3.0.0                    py35_1    <unknown>
pip                       7.1.2                    py35_0    <unknown>
ply                       3.8                      py35_0    <unknown>
psutil                    3.2.2                    py35_0    <unknown>
py                        1.4.30                   py35_0    <unknown>
pyasn1                    0.1.9                    py35_0    <unknown>
pycosat                   0.6.1                    py35_0    <unknown>
pycparser                 2.14                     py35_0    <unknown>
pycrypto                  2.6.1                    py35_3    <unknown>
pycurl                    7.19.5.1                 py35_1    <unknown>
pyflakes                  1.0.0                    py35_0    <unknown>
pygments                  2.0.2                    py35_0    <unknown>
pyopenssl                 0.15.1                   py35_1    <unknown>
pyparsing                 2.0.3                    py35_0    <unknown>
pyqt                      4.11.4                   py35_3    defaults
pyreadline                2.1                      py35_0    <unknown>
pytables                  3.2.2               np110py35_1    <unknown>
pytest                    2.8.1                    py35_0    <unknown>
python                    3.5.0                         3    defaults
python-dateutil           2.4.2                    py35_0    <unknown>
pytz                      2015.7                   py35_0    defaults
pywin32                   219                      py35_1    <unknown>
pyyaml                    3.11                     py35_2    <unknown>
pyzmq                     14.7.0                   py35_1    <unknown>
qt                        4.8.7                    vc14_4  [vc14]  <unknown>
qtconsole                 4.1.0                    py35_0    <unknown>
requests                  2.8.1                    py35_0    <unknown>
rope                      0.9.4                    py35_1    <unknown>
rope-py3k-0.9.4           1                         <pip>
scikit-image              0.11.3              np110py35_0    <unknown>
scikit-learn              0.17                np110py35_1    defaults
scipy                     0.16.0              np110py35_0    <unknown>
setuptools                18.5                     py35_0    defaults
simplegeneric             0.8.1                    py35_0    <unknown>
sip                       4.16.9                   py35_2    defaults
six                       1.10.0                   py35_0    <unknown>
snowballstemmer           1.2.0                    py35_0    <unknown>
sockjs-tornado            1.0.1                    py35_0    <unknown>
sphinx                    1.3.1                    py35_0    <unknown>
sphinx-rtd-theme          0.1.7                     <pip>
sphinx_rtd_theme          0.1.7                    py35_0    <unknown>
spyder                    2.3.7                    py35_3    <unknown>
spyder-app                2.3.7                    py35_0    <unknown>
sqlalchemy                1.0.9                    py35_0    <unknown>
statsmodels               0.6.1               np110py35_0    <unknown>
sympy                     0.7.6.1                  py35_0    <unknown>
tables                    3.2.2                     <pip>
tk                        8.5.18                   vc14_0  [vc14]  <unknown>
toolz                     0.7.4                    py35_0    <unknown>
tornado                   4.3                      py35_0    defaults
traitlets                 4.0.0                    py35_0    <unknown>
ujson                     1.33                     py35_0    <unknown>
unicodecsv                0.14.1                   py35_0    <unknown>
werkzeug                  0.11.2                   py35_0    defaults
wheel                     0.26.0                   py35_1    <unknown>
xlrd                      0.9.4                    py35_0    <unknown>
xlsxwriter                0.7.7                    py35_0    <unknown>
xlwings                   0.5.0                    py35_0    defaults
xlwt                      1.0.0                    py35_0    <unknown>
zeromq                    4.1.3                    vc14_1  [vc14]  <unknown>
zlib                      1.2.8                    vc14_2  [vc14]  <unknown>
```

P.s. I have already tried this: restarted the kernel, reinstalled the anaconda

Need the help to solve this!!

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it is embarrassing. The answer to my question is pretty simple :

I tried importing the PyTabels by "import pytables".

It should be :

```
import tables
```